# extracting data from a column based on another column

Tags: awk

I have some files as shown below. I would like to extract the values of $5 based on $1.

file1

```
sam     60.2    143 40.4    19.8
mathew  107.9   144 35.6    72.3
baby    48.1    145 17.8    30.3
rehna   47.2    146 21.2    26.0
sam     69.9    147 .0      69.9
```

file2

```
baby    58.9    503 47.5    11.4
daisy   20.8    504 20.4    .4
arch    61.1    505 12.3    48.8
sam     106.6   506 101.6   5.0
rehna   73.5    507 35.9    37.6
sam     92.0    508 61.1    30.9
```

I used the following code to extract $5.

```
awk '$1 == "rehna" { print $5 }' *
awk '$1 == "sam" { print $5 }' *
```

I would like to get the output as shown below

```
rehna   sam
26.0    19.8
37.6    69.9
         5.0
        30.9
```

How do I achieve this? your suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is probably to `paste` the results together:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myawk {
    awk -v name="$1" 'BEGIN {print name} $1 == name { print $5 }' file1 file2
}

paste  <(myawk rehna) <(myawk sam)
```

Running this produces the results you requested (with TAB as the separator character).  See `paste` documentation for other options.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34113996/45375) has since wrapped this approach in a function, in the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you want more background information, read on.

Assuming Bash, Ksh, or Zsh as the shell:

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' 'rehna' 'sam'
paste \
     <(awk '$1 == "rehna" { print $5 }' *) \
     <(awk '$1 == "sam"   { print $5 }' *)
```

The above produces *tab*-separated output.

[`paste` is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) that outputs *corresponding* lines from its input files, by default separated with tabs; e.g., `paste fileA fileB` yields:

```
 <line 1 from fileA>\t<line 1 from fileB>
 <line 2 from fileA>\t<line 2 from fileB>
 ...
```

If any input file runs out of lines, it supplies empty lines.

In the case at hand, the respective outputs from the `awk` commands are used as input files, using [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`).